# Problems with formatting of webpage

Tags: html, css

I am having two problems. The first one, is that I am getting a break in FF, IE and chrome between the top img and the logo. The second problem only appears in IE and what happens is there is a border around the logo. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>2E Network - Home</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header"><img src="Images/top_page.png" width="963" height="29"><div id="logo"><a href="/" id="logoimg"><img src="Images/logo.jpg" width="921" height="272" alt="Logo" longdesc="/index.php"></a></div>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
  </div>
  <div id="footer"><img src="Images/bottom_page.png" width="963" height="50">
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Seperate CSS style Sheet

```
body {
 background-image: url(Images/bkg.png);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
#wrapper {
 width: 963px;
 margin: auto;
}
#main {
 background-image: url(Images/wrapper_bkg.png);
 background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
#logo {
 background-image: url(Images/wrapper_bkg.png);
 background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
#logoimg {
 margin-left: 15px;
}
```

[Check the current page here](http://24.24.131.124/index.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to fix the gap make the top image to display:block;
and the border
you can see it here

http://www.jsfiddle.net/CcvTD/2/

edit:updated so the borders are removed too

Comment: you're welcome, if it was what you were looking for feel free to mark this answered :D

Comment: Woa, that's a pretty cool program you found. The only problem is now the image is shifted over.

Comment: @Breezer, not the owner of the question, just liked the use of jsfiddle and the smooth solution :) upvoted!

Comment: oh hehe k :P well jsfiddle is the best ^^

Answer (score 0):

This will get rid of the border:

```
#logoimg img {
  border:0px;
}
```

To fix the gap, try:

```
#header img, #logo {
    margin:0px;
}
```

Comment: Got rid of the border, but the gap is still there